# only one resolution option 480 x 620(4\3)

Tags: graphics

I have installed oracle virtual box on my HP laptop  and set up a virtual hard drive with 21GB of memory. However I cant get the resolution to change from 480 x 620 (4/3). the laptop has a 2GB Nvidia GEFORCE'GT635M

Comment: What model of you HP laptop are ou using, what version of Ubuntu are you using. The more information you provide in your question, the easier and faster it is for us to help you.

Comment: The laptop is a dv7 with a 2GB NVDIA geforce-GT 635M graphics card and the ubuntu vresion is 14.04

Answer (score 1):

Install the Guest Additions in Virtual Box.
In the menu, select 'Devices' and then click on 'Insert Guest Additions CD image'. Run the shell script on the new mounted CD. When it's done, reboot and you should be able to change the resolution.